# Weird core dumped error on linked list example in C

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, coredump

i have the program below. i wanted to practice linked lists and tried to build an app which can save flags entered to the program into a linked list all my controls are working fine about the flags but when i enter everything correct instead of listing the flags i get a core dumped error

## --UPDATE--

The program is supposed to check the flags provided to program whether they are valid or require any value and if everything is ok its supposed to print key value pairs to console which are stored in a linked list
i compile the program by invoking `gcc test.c init.c` and run as `./a.out -test someParam`

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "init.h"
//f for false t for true
const char *flgs[3][2] = {{"-test", "t"}, {"-hey", "f"}, {"-heydehey", "f"}};
int forEach(FLAGS *flags, void (*cb)(char *flag, char *vl)) {
  FLAGS *current = flags;
  if (current == NULL) {
    return -1;
  }
  while (current != NULL) {
    cb(current->flag, current->value);
    current = current->next;
  }
  return 0;
}
FLAGS *initArgs(int argc, char **argv) {
  if (argc < 2) {
    return NULL;
  }
  int flagsNum = 3;
  FLAGS *rtr = malloc(sizeof(FLAGS));
  if (rtr == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "unable to allocate memory\n");
    exit(-1);
  }
  FLAGS *current = NULL;
  rtr->next = current;
  bool invalidFlag = true;
  bool skipNext = false;
  for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    if (skipNext) {
      skipNext = false;
      continue;
    }
    invalidFlag = true;
    if (argv[i][0] == '-') {
      // if flag
      current = malloc(sizeof(FLAGS));
      for (int f = 0; f < 3; f++) {
        if (!strcmp(argv[i], flgs[f][0])) {
          invalidFlag = false;
          if (flgs[f][1] == "t") {
            if (i + 1 == argc || argv[i + 1][0] == '-') {
              fprintf(stderr, "flag %s requires a value ,none given\n", argv[i]);
              exit(-1);
            }
            current->value = argv[i + 1];
            current->next = NULL;
            current = current->next;
            skipNext = true;
          }
          current->flag = argv[i];
        }
      }
      if (invalidFlag) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\x1B[31minvalid flag %s\n", argv[i]);
        exit(-1);
      }
    }
  }
  return rtr;
}
```

and here are my init.h and test.c files

test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "init.h"
void cb(char *, char *);
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  FLAGS *entered = initArgs(argc, argv);
  if (entered == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "an error occured\n");
    return -1;
  }
  forEach(entered, &cb);
  return 0;
}
void cb(char *fl, char *val) { printf("flag=%s; value=%s;\name", fl, val);
 }
```

init.h

```
#define true 1
#define false 0
typedef int bool;
typedef struct values {
  char *flag;
  char *value;
  struct values *next;
} FLAGS;
extern const char *flgs[3][2];
int forEach(FLAGS *, void (*cb)(char *, char *));
FLAGS *initArgs(int argc, char **argv);
```

Comment: Have you tried running the program with a debugger (such as `gdb`)? This will show you precisely the line of code that generates the error.

Comment: @e0k only if i knew how to use gdb :) however i tried using netbeans first of all it wont accept my binary because its compiled as shared object somehow . then  tried to attach to the gdb process it told me permission denied but the user who started gdb and the netbeans was the same user - me.

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed how you invoke the program, what output you expect, and the output you actually get.  That's an important part of an MCVE ([MCVE]), as well as minimal code, which I suspect you've given us.

Comment: You have: `if (flgs[f][1] == "t")` — that is not a good way of comparing strings (the condition is probably going to evaluate to false).  You're using `strcmp()` elsewhere, so it must be a temporary mental block that caused you to write that.  Whether that triggers a core dump is debatable, but it isn't correct.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler i updated the question and about the condition it seems working fine if the flag requires parameter program exits with the error message its fine working only if everything is correct somehow something is happening

Comment: `gdb ./a.out`, then `run`, then when it crashes, `where`.

Comment: @Adam: given that he wants to pass arguments `-test something`, the command should be `run -test something`.  When I run it, it crashes on the line `current->flag = argv[i];` because `current` is a null pointer.  That is probably because of the prior assignment `current = current->next;` in the `if` conditions.

Comment: But I allocate space in the beginning of the if and if that's not a flag it does not require a new allocation should use previously allocated object

Comment: And actually if it does not enter the if block there's no assignment to the current and if it enters it gets allocated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at these lines and my comments:

```
        current->next = NULL;      // Here current->next becomes NULL
        current = current->next;   // so here current becomes NULL
        skipNext = true;
      }
      current->flag = argv[i];     // So here you dereference NULL
```

consequently you get a core dump.